# How do these 2 nested for loops differ in terms of Big Oh

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Loop 1:

> sum $\gets 0$ 
>   for $i\gets 1$ to $n$ do 
>   $~~~~$ for $j \gets 1$ to $i^2$ do 
>   $~~~~~~~~~$ sum $\gets$ sum + ary$[i]$

Loop 2:

> sum $\gets 0$ 
>   for $i\gets 1$ to $n^2$ do 
>   $~~~~$ for $j \gets 1$ to $i$ do 
>   $~~~~~~~~~$ sum $\gets$ sum + ary$[i]$

I know this summation formula is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2=n\left(n+1\right)\left(2n+1\right)/6\sim n^{3}/3,$

Comment: [Please find here how to input code on stackexchange.](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code) (This is probably much easier than the hacks you used...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one runs in
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} = \Theta\left(n^3\right)
$$
and the second one takes
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n^2} i = \frac{n^2\left(n^2+1\right)}{2} = \Theta\left(n^4\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

The numbers of times the inner loop body is executed are

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{i^2}1=\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$$
and
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}\sum_{j=1}^i1=\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}i=\frac{n^2(n^2+1)}2.$$